# Adding new column in pandas, python min function is showing error

Tags: python-3.x

In the code below, `min()` is showing me an error but when I remove `min()` the code works fine.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.data',sep="\t",header=0)
df1=df[['clust_no','chr_gene','tss_no','score']].copy()
#Value error due to the min() function. otherwise code is working
df1['distance'] = min(abs(df['sTSS_gene']-df['eTSS_tf']),abs(df['sTSS_gene']-df['sTSS_tf']))
```

The data:

```
<Tab Separated dataset>
chr_gene    sTSS_gene   eTSS_gene   gene    tss_no  clust_no    chr_tf  sTSS_tf eTSS_tf score   tf
chr1    28586028    28609002    SESN2   1   17  chr1    28586689    28587038    20.6444 p53
chr1    39351477    39395185    RHBDL2  2   35  chr1    39367275    39367475    7.74752 p53
chr1    39351478    39407502    RHBDL2  1   35  chr1    39367275    39367475    7.74752 p53
```

Anybody knows what the reason is?

Comment: Can you please share some sample data, and some details about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @SupratimHaldar
I need to add a column which is minimum difference between two values.
New column will be added in df1['distance'] i.e. Minimum difference value between two columns[min(dif(col2:sTSS_gene and col8:sTSS_tf), dif(col2:sTSS_gene and col9:eTSS_tf)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get an element-wise min value. So, use `numpy.minimum()` instead.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df1['distance'] = np.minimum(abs(df['sTSS_gene']-df['eTSS_tf']),abs(df['sTSS_gene']-df['sTSS_tf']))
>>> df1
   clust_no chr_gene  tss_no     score  distance
0        17     chr1       1  20.64440       661
1        35     chr1       2   7.74752     15798
2        35     chr1       1   7.74752     15797
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Please upvote and accept the answer in that case :)